How to Load Project Files into the Editor when the Scratch app starts?
I have a .sb3 file that is returned from an API, and I want to load it into the editor when the app starts.
It seems that I need to set the project files into scratch-storage, but I am not sure if this is correct or how to do it.
Could someone please guide me on how to load the .sb3 file into the editor when the app starts?

@Gyul thanks for your edit! was there enough information or something missing in my question? I ask this just because I am happy for improvements

You can edit componentDidMount of vm-manager-hoc.jsx as bellow:


// Define download file function
async function loadSb3FromApi(url, vm) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const projectBlob = await response.blob();
    const arrayBuffer = await projectBlob.arrayBuffer();
    await vm.loadProject(arrayBuffer);  // Loads the project into the Scratch VM
}

componentDidMount () {
  if (!this.props.vm.initialized) {
      this.audioEngine = new AudioEngine();
      this.props.vm.attachAudioEngine(this.audioEngine);
      this.props.vm.setCompatibilityMode(true);
      this.props.vm.initialized = true;
      this.props.vm.setLocale(this.props.locale, this.props.messages);
  }
  if (!this.props.isPlayerOnly && !this.props.isStarted) {
      this.props.vm.start();
  }

  // Fetch and load the project from the API when the app starts
  loadSb3FromApi("URL_FILE", this.props.vm).then(() => {
      console.log('Project loaded successfully');
  }).catch(err => {
      console.error('Error loading project:', err);
  });

  // Initialize and start the VM
  this.props.vm.start();
}




Hi @qkhuyit thanks for your response! I tried following what you said but it gave me this error, do you know what am I doing wrong?
vm-manager-hoc.jsx:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined at _loadSb3FromApi (vm-manager-hoc.jsx:17:1) at loadSb3FromApi (vm-manager-hoc.jsx:17:1) at VMManager.componentDidMount (vm-manager-hoc.jsx:50:1) at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:19814:1) at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:22803:1) at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188:1)
